# switch trips breaker when turned on if bulb is in

Tags: electrical

I have light s on the same breaker all works but when I turn island light on without light bulb it's good but once bulb is in and turned on it trips.

Comment: Is this an incandescent, halogen, CFL, or LED bulb that is doing this?

Comment: What happens if you use a different bulb?

Comment: Can you remove the lamp and see if the breaker still trips?

Answer (score 1):

The bulb is either overloading the circuit (if the circuit is that close to overload, you have big problems), or creating a short-circuit.  I'd say it's more likely that the light fixture is wired incorrectly, or there's a short-circuit in the 'bulb' itself (more likely if it's a CFL, or LED).

Try a different 'bulb', and inspect the fixture wiring.